# partial differential equation for ruled surfaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

We say that a surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ is ruled if for each point $p$ in the surface there is a line that passes through $p$ and is contained in the surface. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruled_surface for more information.

Does anybody know if there is a partial differential equation whose solutions are all ruled surfaces and only them? And what is the equation? Some reference would be helpful, too (different from Salmon's old book about surfaces which I unfortunately find unreadable).

Comment: When you write "Does anybody know if there is a partial differential equation whose solutions are all ruled surfaces and only them?", do you mean to ask whether there is a partial differential equation that *characterizes* ruled surfaces?  The natural PDE that does this is the one that sets equal to zero the product of the curvatures of the asymptotic curves.  It's a 3rd order equation, and the general solution depends on 3 functions of 1 variable, as you'd expect.  This equation is projectively invariant, so it is better to express it directly in terms of projective invariants.

Comment: yes, i'm looking for a partial equation that characterizes the ruled surfaces, but preferably for surfaces given by $f(x,y,z)=0$ and not in the parametric form. so if we're given a surface $f(x,y,z)=0$ we just plug in $f$ in the partial equation and we know that it's ruled iff we get 0. 

Comment: here http://faculty.fairfield.edu/jmac/rs/halftw.htm they mention an equation $x^2z_{xx}+2xyz_{xy}+y^2z_{yy}=0$, but it's not the right one, it misses e.g. $z=xy$ (probably this equation gives only a subclass of the ruled surfaces).

Comment: @filipm: I doubt that such a PDE for $f(x,y,z)$ can exist since $f$ is allowed to do whatever it wants outside its zero locus (except becoming zero). So any nonzero function should be a solution of the PDE but I guess that just leaves the empty equation.

Comment: @michael: ok, sorry, i see you're right. in fact, i'd be satisfied with the form $z=f(x,y)$, i.e. if the surface is described parametrically as $(x,y,f(x,y))$. then i'm looking for a partial equation in $f$.

Comment: @Michael:  Well, it's not completely out of the question if you modify your request a little bit:  What filipm could be asking for is a partial differential expression $E(f)$ (say, polynomial in $f$ and its derivatives) such that, whenever $E(f)$ vanishes along the locus $f=0$, then the locus $f=0$ is ruled.  Even this is asking too much, though; you'd probably need to assume that $d f$ is non-vanishing along the locus $f=0$ in order to get the ruled conclusion. (Otherwise, you could replace $f$ by a high power of $f$ to make $E(f)$ vanish.)  One expects such an $E(f)$ to be 3rd order in $f$.

Comment: @filipm:  In that case, set $II = f_{xx} dx^2 + 2f_{xy}dxdy + f_{yy}dy^2$.  If the discriminant of $II$ vanishes, then the surface is ruled.  If the discriminant is positive, it is not ruled.  If the discriminant is negative, compute $III = f_{xxx}dx^3+3f_{xxy}dx^2dy+3f_{xyy}dxdy^2+f_{yyy}dy^3$ and let $III_0$ be the $II$-trace-free part of $III$.  Then the surface is ruled if and only if the discriminant of $III_0$ vanishes.

Comment: @Robert: thanks for expanding on that. You're right.

Comment: @Robert(concerning your last comment): that's exactly the kind of answer i was looking for, except that i don't understand what is the "II-trace-free part of III" and "discriminant" (is it the same as here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant?). also, if you want you can put your comment as an answer. thx.

Comment: @filipm:  OK. Done.

Comment: @Michael There exists a non-linear differential operator $H(f)$ which is a polynomial in the partial derivatives of $f$ of order up to three, such that $f=H(f)=0$ defines the flecnodal locus of the surface $f=0$. This was proved by Salmon in the book that filipm mentions. A surface is ruled if and only if all points are flecnodal, i.e., $H(f)$ vanishes identically on $f=0$. I have never seen $H(f)$ written out explicitly. Salmon uses some undecipherable weird 19th century invariant theory notation. I would also like to see this written out. 

Comment: @Felipe: You could write H(f) out, starting with my indications of an algorithm below, but the answer won't be nice and may not be comprehensible. Even in the parametric form that filipm was willing to settle for, the vanishing of the resultant I mention below is a polynomial of degree 5 in the second and third derivatives of f, and it has 13 terms. I doubt you'll get much useful information out of it, any more than you get much useful information from the explicit formula for the Gauss curvature in terms of the derivatives of E, F, and G. 

Comment: @Robert: I've tried once. I couldn't do it by hand and didn't see an efficient way of doing it on the computer. I know it won't be pretty, but I'd like to see it done.

Comment: @Felipe:  For $z=f(x,y)$, it's the equation
${f_{yy}}^3{f_{xxx}}^2+6{f_{yy}}{f_{xxx}}{f_{yyy}}{f_{xy}}{f_{xx}}$ 
$-6{f_{yy}}^2{f_{xxx}}{f_{xyy}}{f_{xx}}-6{f_{yyy}}{f_{xy}}{f_{xx}}^2{f_{xyy}}$
$+9{f_{yy}}{f_{xyy}}^2{f_{xx}}^2-6{f_{xy}}{f_{yy}}^2{f_{xxy}}{f_{xxx}}$
$+12{f_{xy}}^2{f_{xxy}}{f_{yyy}}{f_{xx}}-18{f_{xy}}{f_{yy}}{f_{xxy}}{f_{xyy}}{f_{xx}}$
$+12{f_{yy}}{f_{xyy}}{f_{xy}}^2{f_{xxx}}-8{f_{yyy}}{f_{xy}}^3{f_{xxx}}$
$+9{f_{xx}}{f_{yy}}^2{f_{xxy}}^2-6{f_{yy}}{f_{xxy}}{f_{yyy}}{f_{xx}}^2$
$+{f_{yyy}}^2{f_{xx}}^3 = 0$.

Comment: Final comment:  To get the nonparametric form for surfaces $F(x,y,z)=0$, start with the parametric equation $z = f(x,y)$ and think $F(x,y,f(x,y))=0$.
By implicit differentiation, $f_x=-F_x/F_z$, while $f_{xx}=-( {F_z}^2F_{xx}-2F_xF_zF_{xz}+{F_x}^2F_{zz})/{F_z}^3$, etc.  Now substitute into the formula for $f$ given above and clear the denominator (a power of $F_z$), yielding a polynomial $H(F)$ in $F$ and its derivatives of order at most $3$.  If $F$ is a reduced polynomial (no multiple factors), 
then the components of $F=0$ of nonpositive curvature 
on which $H(F)$ vanishes will be ruled.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a test for when a surface of the form $z = f(x,y)$, where $f$ is a sufficiently smooth function of two variables, is ruled.

To begin, set $I\!I = f_{xx} dx^2 + 2f_{xy}dxdy + f_{yy}dy^2$.  If $I\!I$ vanishes identically, then the surface is a plane, so it is ruled.

Suppose that $I\!I$ is nonzero.  The *discriminant* of $I\!I$ is defined (up to a factor of $(\mathrm{d}x\wedge\mathrm{d}y)^{\otimes 2}$) to be
$$
\Delta(I\!I) = f_{xx}f_{yy}- {f_{xy}}^2.
$$

If $\Delta(I\!I) >0$, then the surface is locally strictly convex and so cannot be ruled.

If $\Delta(I\!I) = 0$, then the surface is ruled.  In fact, it has vanishing Gauss curvature.  Moreover, $I\!I = \pm \alpha^2$ for some nonzero $1$-form $\alpha$ on the domain of $f$, and the curves in this domain defined by $\alpha = 0$ (which turn out to be straight lines) lift to the graph $z = f(x,y)$ to be straight lines.

If $\Delta(I\!I) < 0$, 
set $I\!I\!I = f_{xxx}\ dx^3+3f_{xxy}\ dx^2dy+3f_{xyy}\ dxdy^2+f_{yyy}\ dy^3$ 
and let $I\!I\!I_0$ be the $I\!I$-trace-free part of $I\!I\!I$.  Then the surface $z = f(x,y)$ is ruled if and only if the discriminant of $I\!I\!I_0$ vanishes.

(Added later:  This latter condition (i.e., the vanishing of the discriminant of $I\!I\!I_0$) turns out to be equivalent to the condition that $I\!I$ and $I\!I\!I$ have a common linear factor, say, $\alpha$ (which will necessarily be real when $\Delta(I\!I) < 0$), and hence is equivalent to the vanishing of the *resultant* of $I\!I$ and $I\!I\!I$, i.e., $\textrm{Reslt}(I\!I,I\!I\!I) = 0$.  When such an $\alpha$ exists, the leaves of $\alpha=0$ are lines on the surface.)

*Notes:*

1. The discriminant of a cubic form $C = p\ dx^3 + 3q\ dx^2dy + 3r\ dxdy^2 + s\ dy^3$ is, by definition,
   $$
   \Delta(C) = s^2p^2 + 4r^3p + 4 q^3s - 3 r^2q^2 - 6 sqrp.
   $$
   It is, up to a multiple, the unique polynomial of degree $4$ in the coefficients that vanishes if and only if $C$ has a multiple factor.
2. Given a quadratic form $Q = a\ dx^2 + 2b\ dxdy + c\ dy^2$ with nonvanishing discriminant $D$, the $Q$-trace of a form $C$ of degree $3$ is the linear form
   $$
   tr_Q(C ) = \frac{(ar-2bq+cp)\ dx +  (as-2br+cq)\ dy}{D}.
   $$
   Any cubic form $C$ can be uniquely written in the form
   $$
   C = C_0 + L\cdot Q
   $$
   where $L$ is a linear form and $tr_Q(C_0) = 0$.  (In fact, $L = \tfrac34 tr_Q(C)$.)  The term $C_0$ is called the $Q$-trace-free part of $C$.
3. The resultant $\textrm{Reslt}(Q,C)$ of a quadratic form $Q$ and a cubic form $C$ is the (unique up to nonzero multiples) polynomial that is cubic in the coefficients of $Q$, quadratic in the coefficients of $C$, and vanishes exactly when they have a common linear divisor.

Comment: It is easy to see that the condition that II and III have a common *real* linear factor is necessary for the surface to be ruled: just parametrize a line on the surface as $( x_0+at, y_0+bt, z_0+ct=f(x_0+at,y_0+bt) )$ and differentiate 3 times wrt $t$. Is there a good reference to the proof that the condition is sufficient?

Comment: @MikhailSkopenkov:  I don't know a reference off the top of my head, but I am sure that it is somewhere in the classical affine geometry literature.  Maybe one should ask Udo Simon or Gary Jensen, both of whom have books on classical affine geometry of surfaces.  Maybe Blaschke is a good reference; have a look at his book on the subject.  The proof that I know is just the obvious one using moving frames.  Actually, since it is a projective geometry fact, this ought to be in the classical projective geometry literature, but I'm not that familiar with that literature. Maybe Svec or Wilczinski?

Comment: Many thanks! The exposition of this result in the Blaschke book is a bit cumbersome, thus let us try the other ones.

Comment: @RobertBryant, why the curves in the domain defined by $\alpha=0$ must be straight lines? I know it is a comment fact that surface with vanishing Gaussian curvature everywhere must be ruled surfaces, but I cannot find a simple proof. Could you explain to me a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: @student This is not obviuos. We are currently writing a paper on that. If you give your e-mail address (say, via private message), we could send you a draft.

Comment: @student:  I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you asking why the null curves of the second fundamental form must be straight lines if the Gauss curvature vanishes?  This is treated in any good curves-and-surfaces book on differential geometry:  The principal curves of curvature zero are straight lines, as follows immediately from the structure equations.   A slighly more subtle argument shows that when $I\!I$ and $I\!I\!I$ have a common (real) factor, then the null curves of this factor are straight lines.  But, again, this follows (with a little more work) from the struture equations.

Comment: @RobertBryant Although painstakingly obtained this expression, it seems that there is still a need to limit the scope of application. Like the paraboloid $z=x^2+y^2$, this surface is not ruled surface, but it satisfies the partial differential equation.

Comment: @user165013:  If you read carefully, I did not claim that the equation alone sufficed to imply that a surface was ruled.  I claimed that it suffices when $\Delta(I\!I) <0$.  In your 'counter-example', $\Delta(I\!I) >0$.

Comment: A proof that if II and III have a common real factor, then through a **generic** point of the surface there passes a straight line segment contained in the surface, is written in https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.01444, Section 3. However we do not know if there must be a line through **each** point of the surface.

Answer (score 7):

From the paper to which 'lowerbound' linked, "Symmetry groups and Lagrangians associated with Tzitzeica surfaces," by Nicoleta Bila (also [arXiv:math/9910138v1](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910138)), here is Theorem 1 and its preamble:
Consider $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and let

   [image: Tz1]

   [image]

---

I take no credit (or blame!) for this; just posting as a community service.

Comment: Joseph, how do you insert a pdf document in an MO answer box ?  You have even managed to insert material from two different pages without  showing the page break.  I would like to use the trick...

Comment: @Chandan: I converted the PDF to JPEG (actually, to two JPEGs) and then included each as images with the HTML img-tag.

Answer (score 3):

> Does anybody know if there is a partial differential equation whose solutions are all ruled surfaces and only them?

An example is theorem 1 of http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/BJGA/10.1/bt-bil.pdf

Edit: I have made this a community wiki answer so that if anyone would care to type in the theorem then they are free to do so.

Comment: Would you care to type in the theorem? There is no guarantee that this pdf file will stay at that location for the lifetime of MO. 

Comment: @david: last time I did this for you the question was closed so I'm not going to spend the effort this time.  see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77643/pythagorean-analogue/77645

Comment: @David: If you look at the paper, you will see that typing in all the requisite notation is a bit painful. Perhaps including the math review pointer is a more practical solution.

Comment: @david: I see that in my 'pythagorean analogue' answer you asked me to summarize the important points while at the same time you voted to close the question.

Comment: The cited theorem has nothing to do with characterization of ruled surfaces. It is on characterization of a very-restricted class of so-called Tzitzeica surfaces, which can be ruled or not.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, for bivariate functions $z=u(x,y)$, let's write down the following notation

\begin{gather*} 
r=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial\,\!x^2}\qquad\,s=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial\,\!x\partial\,\!y}\qquad\,t=\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial\,\!y^2}\\ 
\\ 
\lambda_1=\dfrac{-s+\sqrt{s^2-rt}}{t}\qquad\,\lambda_2=\dfrac{-s-\sqrt{s^2-rt}}{t}\\ 
\\ 
\Diamond\,\!u=\dfrac{\partial\,\!\lambda_1}{\partial\,\!x}+\lambda_1\dfrac{\partial\,\!\lambda_1}{\partial\,\!y} 
\\\\ 
\bar\Diamond\,\!u=\dfrac{\partial\,\!\lambda_2}{\partial\,\!x}+\lambda_2\dfrac{\partial\,\!\lambda_2}{\partial\,\!y} 
\end{gather*}

1. If the smooth surface $z=u(x,y)$ is ruled, also required $t\ne0$, then the bivariate function $z=u(x,y)$ satisfies the third order partial differential equation $\Diamond\,\!u=0$   **or**   $\bar\Diamond\,\!u=0$;
2. If the bivariate function $z=u(x,y)$ satisfies the third-order partial differential equation $\Diamond\,\!u=0$ **or** $\bar\Diamond\,\!u=0$, also satisfies the inequality $s^2-rt\ge0$ and $t\ne0$, the surface represented by it is ruled.

Cf. [Monge 1780] Gaspard Monge, “Mémoire sur les Propriétés de plusieurs genres de
Surfaces courbes, particulièrement sur celles des Surfaces développables,
avec une Application à la Théorie des Ombres et des Pénombres”, Savans
Étrangers 9 (1780), pp.382-440.

https://archive.org/details/mmoiresdemath09acad/page/434

Cf. [J. Ockendon, S. Howison, A. Lacey, A. Movchan] Applied Partial Differential Equations (2003), pp.380-382.

**Example:** $u(x,y)=\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, i.e. $z=\dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$; Assume that $x>y>0$, then

\begin{gather*} 
\begin{split}
r&=+\dfrac{2(x^2-3y^2)xy}{(x^2 +y^2)^3}\\\\
s&=-\dfrac{(x^2 - 2 x y - y^2) (x^2 + 2 x y - y^2)}{(x^2 +y^2)^3}\\\\
t&=-\dfrac{2(3x^2-y^2)xy}{(x^2 +y^2)^3}\\\\
\sqrt{s^2-rt}&=\dfrac{\left|x^2-y^2\right|}{(x^2 +y^2)^2}=\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2 +y^2)^2}>0\\ 
\end{split}\\
\\ 
\lambda_1=-\dfrac{(x^2-3y^2)x}{(3x^2-y^2)y}\qquad\,\lambda_2=\dfrac{y}{x}\\ 
\\ 
\begin{split}
&\color{red}{\Diamond\,\!u=-\dfrac{3(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2)^3}{(3x^2-y^2)^3y^3}}\\
&\color{red}{\phantom{\Diamond\,\!u}<0}\\
\\
&\color{blue}{\bar\Diamond\,\!u\equiv0}
\end{split}
\end{gather*}

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it just $K = 0$, where $K$ is the Gauss curvature?

Wrong. Although surface with zero Gauss curvature is necessarily ruled, the converse is not true. The catenoid is the best known counterexample. See comments below.

Comment: A surface can still be ruled without $K = 0$.  For example, one principal curvature could be positive and the other negative, so the second fundamental form still has null directions; if you're lucky enough, they line up in space.  The catenoid in particular is ruled but curvy.

Comment: The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces shows a formula for the Gaussian curvature of a ruled surface, and gives conditions on when it vanishes.

Comment: Oops. That's right. You just need a null direction that propagates along a straight line. Gotta downvote my own answer.


Comment: Geez. I'm not allowed to downvote my own answer? I can see not allowing own upvotes but why not downvotes?

Comment: You have paid public penance enough! :-) You can just delete your answer; I doubt the commenters would mind.

Comment: I think it's useful to leave it. I will edit it. 

Comment: An obvious example of a ruled surface with $K<0$: a one-sheet hyperboloid.

Comment: The hyperbolic paraboloid is even doubly ruled with $K<0$.

Answer (score 1):

The only chracterization of ruled surfaces I know is the following: 
A surface S in the 3-dimensional Euclidean space of negative Gaussian curvature is a ruled surface iff its (equi)affine Pick-invariant vanishes identically on S.

This theorem can be found in the books of W. Blaschke on Affine Differential Geometry.

For surfaces of positive Gaussian curvature the following theorem is valid:
A surface S in the n-dimensional Euclidean space of positive Gaussian curvature is a quadric  iff its (equi)affine Pick-invariant vanishes identically on S.

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Pick-invariant=0 is the required PDE (perhaps). Although seems very difficult to write down explicitly in terms of the original surface.